# Why does the A320 right aileron float on dual engine failure?

Tags: airbus-a320, engine-failure, ailerons, hydraulic-system

On [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/48326/8730) for the A320 after dual engine failure it says:

> When the hydraulic power is lost, the right aileron is lost, and is in the upfloat position.

Why would this affect only the right aileron?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming it's zero fuel dual engine failure with no chance of [powering up the APU](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/51161/14897), the plane is left with the Ram Air Turbine (RAT).

1. The emergency electrical configuration only powers ELAC 1, one of the two units that control the ailerons, and ELAC 2 is lost *(see below).*

[image]
(A320 FCOM)

2. The RAT powers only the Blue hydraulic system.

Add those two conditions with the color coded schematic below:

[image]
(Airbus Training Manual)

And the right aileron will not be powered. The same schematic can be found in the FCOM under Flight Controls > General > Architecture (27-10-20), the one above is clearer though.